# Is there some support for MsSQL on modules like Peewee?

Tags: python, sql-server, peewee

Peewee made accessing the database really easily, but it doesn't seem to support MSSQL, is there another module that supports it and works similar to Peewee? Data model classes, and nicer sql query constructions?

I'm using pymssql right now but I don't believe they have data models that can represent tables.

Answer (score 2):

The [peewee-mssql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/peewee-mssql) module was recently created for anyone looking for MSSQL support in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, but there is a section in the docs with all the info you need for adding support:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#adding-a-new-database-driver

Comment: If you end up implementing this, I'd be interested in merging as a `playhouse` extension module.